# Scala trait - Is there an equivalent of Java interface public static field?

Tags: java, scala, static, public, traits

In Java:

```
public interface Foo {

  public static final int Bar = 0;
}
```

And in Scala, how can I create a `trait Foo` that has `Bar`, and I can access it as: `Foo.Bar`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can create a companion object (to make it the equivalent of static) and define the variable there using the final val keywords (to make it the equivalent of a final constant):

```
trait Foo { }

object Foo { 
  final val Bar = 0
}
```

Lots more on this [here](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/selfless_trait_pattern.html)

Comment: Making it a `final val` will make it work like Java -- ie, as a constant, instead of a value that is read every time.